# Windows Bridged Networks IP Confict

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I am trying to do the following

Device -> Win10 Ethernet Adapter -> Win 10 Wireless Adapter -> Router

I've bridged the networks following multiple guides. The issue that I am having is that the Device was a Roku (but also tried with a Linux laptop) is getting the same IP address that has been given to the Windows 10 Ethernet adapter. I'm then not able to route any traffic (Wireshark is also showing IP conflicts going on).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you may be using static IP addresses rather than DHCP provided ones. If you have a router capable of acting as DHCP provider, try setting all adapters to automatic IP address before setting up the bridge. Also, if you do use DHCP, try setting up IP leases, and double check the MAC addresses for those leases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some of what you said indicates something seems wrong.

Why are you talking about IP addresses when you're talking about bridging?

Passing along traffic is called routing when you're talking about IP addresses (OSI Model Layer 3).  Bridging refers to lower levels of the OSI Model: Layer 2 (Ethernet / WiFi).

If everything is being successfully bridged, then I would expect the "Layer 2"-based traffic of the DHCP protocol would work, allowing DHCP to assign a Layer 3 address that doesn't conflict.

With older versions of Windows, I would think that routing and bridging are functionality that you may get from the software component called RRAS, which stands for "Routing and Remote Access Services".  This was included in the Windows Server products (e.g. Windows Server 2003), not the "end user"/desktop versions of Microsoft Windows (e.g., Windows XP).  I just checked my Windows 10 machine, under Programs and Features, Windows Features, and did not see it listed.

Please provide the following information (by updating this question, or accepting this answer and creating a new question) :
How are you trying to enable bridging?
What IP addresses are assigned to every device in the above diagram?
What is the setting for the subnet size of each NIC that has an IP address?  (If you're using IPv4 addresses,  you can answer this by providing the subnet mask.)
How is each IP address assigned?  (As a static IP address, or DHCP?)

You shouldn't be getting IP address conflicts.  So that is one thing that looks wrong.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I've actually realised that this is some wierd issue with the Roku device I am using, as I now have bridging working great using a Laptop via the Windows Ethernet Bridge.